# WPF Attached DependencyProperty -- how are local values resolved?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

With respect to DependencyProperty which are not attached, it is my understanding -- and pls correct me if I am wrong as I am a beginner -- that the procees of resolution of local value is based on figuring out first, per a given DependencyProperty in question, what is the key of that DependencyProperty.  The key is a hash code, or some unique value, representing the type of the owner of the DependencyProperty as well as the name of the property (e.g., background).

Once this key is calculated, the value resolution process proceeds to find a mtach for that key withing a dictionary which belongs to the parent type and which contains keys of DependencyProperty (just as explained in previous sentence) and corresponding values which were set locally  with the DependencyProperty Set wrapper (e.g., SetBackground) corresponding to the DependencyProperty in question.  If the key is found within the dictionary, then the local value is considered resolved and the value dound in the dictionary is the value we look for.

However, if the Set wrapper was not used before per the owner control such that the dictionary mentioned in previous paragraph (DependencyProperty keys and values) does not contain the key we seek to find, then the value resolution process proceeds to move up in the logical hierarchy to next parent control and apply the same resolution process with respect to the parent control.  That is, a key composed of the *parent* type and the same name of the property is sought in the key/values dictionary belonging to the parent control.  If it's found this time, then resolution is complete; otherwise, the local value resolution proceeds to the next control in the logical hierarchy, and the process repeats on itself, until the DependencyProperty's value is resolved.  If no value is found, a different way of determination is employed that is not dependent on setting the value locally.

This is more or less the process for DependencyProperty which is not attached. I was wondering if anyone could tell me what is the value resolution process (of local value) per such property.  I assume that the key value dictionary is one which resides in an external control (i.e., not the control in which the DependencyProperty resides), correct ?  This might be the dictionary into which values are stored(using the Set[Proeprtyname]) with respect to DependencyProperty whose parent is that *external* control (which must be static).

Much appreciation if anyone can shed some more light about the Attached DependencyProperty.

Answer (score 0):

Attached properties do not cascade. That is, if you don't explicitly set the value on the control, then it defaults to the `DefaultValue` defined in the property definition.